# How to debug browser caching for web development

Tags: debugging, firefox, caching, http-headers

I am currently working on optimising the caching setup for a website.  I have come up against a lot of situations where the cache headers sent from the server appear to be correct, but then my browser (Firefox in my case) doesn't issue the expected request headers on subsequent page loads.  The logic the browser goes through to decide which request headers to send seems to be completely hidden.

Are there any development tools available that can, for instance, show clearly why Firefox (or any other browser) is, or is not, sending a "If-Modified-Since" header on a case-by-case basis?  Or perhaps there is an advanced log I can activate on the browser that will report the steps it is going through.  My current development workflow is a bit like trying to do coding without having access to any error reports or a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the Firefox [network monitor](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor) you can click on the line where the file is loaded and view all headers etc.

Comment: Thanks, but to give you a better idea of what I'm after, I'd love to be able to expand further information for each header and see the reason why it has been included in the request - a bit like how the "Computed" tab on the Inspector works for CSS, where you can see the logic behind why a particular attribute is being applied to the selected element.

Comment: Or put another way.  Currently, if a request header doesn't appear when I expect it to, I need to try to guess why it's not there and try adjusting things to encourage it to appear.  Either that, or read broadly around the whole subject to try to understand where I'm going wrong.  This is frustrating because the browser will "know" exactly why it's not including the header, and I would just like it to tell me the reason (via some kind of debugger, or log file).

Comment: So you want some kind of network header troubleshooting tool that explains why e.g. a file is not cached? Sounds like something you should ask for on https://ffdevtools.uservoice.com